contentResolver album art does not exists but cannot insert it to MediaStore
My device is an Android 11 (API level 29).
I am trying to get album arts (for queried songs) from the contentResolver, and if they do not exist, I want to insert one.
This is my code so far:
val folders = mutableSetOf<File>()
if (relPath.path.isNotEmpty())
    folders.add(File(relPath.path, ".."))
val audioFiles = mutableListOf<AudioFile>()
val currentDir = File("")
val projection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
)
val sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, sortOrder)?.use {
    val idIdx = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
    val titleIdx = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
    val albumIdx = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)
    val albumIdIdx = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)
    val artistIdx = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
    val durationIdx = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)
    val fileRelPathIdx = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH)
    val displayNameIdx = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
    while (it.moveToNext()) {
        val fileRelPath = File(it.getString(fileRelPathIdx).let { if (it == "/") "" else it })

        if (currentDir == fileRelPath) {  // only fetch songs if they are in this directory
            val id = it.getLong(idIdx)  // TODO getColumnIndexOrThrow
            val title = it.getString(titleIdx)
            val album = it.getString(albumIdx)
            val albumId = it.getLong(albumIdIdx)
            val artist = it.getString(artistIdx)
            val duration = it.getLong(durationIdx)
            val displayName = it.getString(displayNameIdx)

//////////////////////// fetch cover art
            val albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"), albumId)
            var coverArt: Bitmap? = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {try {
                contentResolver.loadThumbnail(albumArtUri, android.util.Size(100, 100), null)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                null
            }} else {
                var albumArtPath: String? = null
                contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART), "${MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID} = ?", arrayOf(albumId.toString()), null)?.use {
                    if (it.moveToFirst())
                        albumArtPath = it.getString(it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART))
                 }
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(albumArtPath)
            }
////////////////////// end fetch cover art
            audioFiles.add(AudioFile(id, title, album, artist, coverArt, duration))
        }


        // 
        fileRelPath.toRelativeString(relPath).substringBefore('/').takeIf(String::isNotEmpty)?.let { folders.add(if (relPath.path.isEmpty()) File(it) else File(relPath.path, it)) }

    }

}

In the end, to my surprise, none of my songs have an album art (using contentResolver).
$ adb shell content query --uri "content://media/external/audio/albumart"
No result found.
$ adb shell content query --uri "content://media/external/audio/albums" | grep -vc album_art=NULL
0

So currently I am using MediaMetadataRetriever() to fetch the album art:
val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
retriever.setDataSource(File(File("/sdcard", fileRelPath.path), displayName).path)
val data = retriever.embeddedPicture
retriever.release()
if (data != null) {
    coverArt = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.size)
}

Apparently I should insert album arts myself in MediaStore: How can I update the album art path using contentResolver?
This is my attempt for a single album art:
val albumArtUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
val values = ContentValues().apply {
    put("album_id", albumId)
    put("_data", "/sdcard/cover.jpg")  // this image does exist
}
contentResolver.insert(albumArtUri, values)

But I get the Error:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table album_art has no column named _id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO album_art (_data,_id) VALUES (?,_GET_ID( '/storage/emulated/0/Music/_.thumbnails/1730630794351.jpg' ))

I have 3 questions:

is it normal I don't have any cached album arts in MediaStore? I have 4300 songs, some with embedded covers, others with "cover.jpg" in the same folder (so there is no problem there).
since I don't have album art in MediaStore, should I try to insert it?
what is the error I get when trying to insert one? /storage/emulated/0/Music/_.thumbnails/1730630794351.jpg does not exist (the folder was created at the same time as the error though)

I have these in my Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />

So it should be fine(?)

Android scans the mp3 tags and so builds its media database. You should update the metadata (albumart) of the track itself. Android will then pick it up, ohterwise a subsequent scan would remove the metadata if not found on the tags
